# Failing to create managed package with prompts

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package

I created in-app guidance in scratch org, pulled, and ran:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --package "{packageName}" --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --wait 10 --installationkeybypass
```

Am getting **These entities are not supported: [Prompt]**

Ideas?

Comment: https://mdcoverage.secure.force.com/docs/metadata-coverage/ says that `Prompt` isn't supported in a managed 2GP, which would explain your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported and a widely requested feature.

It is documented that it is not supported in 2GP managed packages as of [now](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/53).

This has been raised internally and the teams are looking how to support it in the future.

For now you can package this separately as an unlocked package.

Comment: I would add to this that Managed Packages are most commonly used by partners to distribute an application. As far as I'm aware, it is against the partner TOS to distribute using unlocked packages.

Comment: On TOS yes thats something that one should work it out with respective AE or PAM or a TE. I see great chances of getting it exempted for one such scenarios like this where you just need to distribute something thats not package-able right now. I am not asking to put everything as unlocked package.

Comment: Oh I thought it was blanket no-go for unlocked packages. If exceptions are possible I stand corrected, thank you!